# Grid of images that can toggle, need help saving selected images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of images that I can toggle. In each cell I can toggle among several images and if I stop toggling for 5 seconds it will be persisted somehow (not yet determined, just alerting it).

Where I'm having trouble is if I click once in several different cells (let's say I click once in 3 different cells under 5 seconds. I will only get 1 saved alert instead of 3. Can someone help me with my design?

The idea of the program is a checklist that a user can toggle a cell to show status for task. Like a checkmark image, question image, etc.

Other suggestions for design are welcomed. Would objects work better here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test 123</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: teal;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td><img class="imgX" src="pic0.png" alt="No Pic" /></td>
            <td><img class="imgX" src="pic0.png" alt="No Pic" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><img class="imgX" src="pic0.png" alt="No Pic" /></td>
            <td><img class="imgX" src="pic0.png" alt="No Pic" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var clicks = 0;
            var timer;

            $('.imgX').on('click', function () {
                var fileName = $(this).attr('src');
                var re = /(pic)(.*)(.png)/;
                var imgNumber = fileName.match(re)[2]; //todo: why array
                clicks = Number(imgNumber) + 1;

                if (clicks > 3) clicks = 0;

                var eleImage = $(this).attr('src', 'pic{0}.png'.replace('{0}', clicks));

                //Save image if 5 seconds have passed
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    alert('saved');
                }, 5000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {


        $('.imgX').on('click', function () {
             var clicks = 0;
        var timer;
            var fileName = $(this).attr('src');
            var re = /(pic)(.*)(.png)/;
            var imgNumber = fileName.match(re)[2]; //todo: why array
            clicks = Number(imgNumber) + 1;

            if (clicks > 3) clicks = 0;

            var eleImage = $(this).attr('src', 'pic{0}.png'.replace('{0}', clicks));

            //Save image if 5 seconds have passed
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                alert('saved');
            }, 5000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Actually you are calling the function with same variable (click and timer) being overridden. If you put these variables inside the click function, then they will be created as new for every click event

Comment: If done this way, if you click in the same cell several times you'll get that many alerts. So that's not going to work.